# How Can I print all docs fields that created by logged in user

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

in carsData collection all users put there cars docs. I want to print just the logged in user docs fields without another users data .
how can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check this [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#filtering) for more information.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('carsData')
            .where('uid', isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
            .get();
```